# Dynamically added spinner with same list items

Tags: android, android-layout, arraylist, drop-down-menu, android-spinner

I am developing a android application in which has a spinner and an Add button. On a click of add button, the spinner gets added in a container layout. The spinner has list of items. I want to display the same list inside a 2nd spinner without the item which has been selected in the first spinner and every time on the click of add button new spinner should get added with the list without the items which are already selected in previous spinners.

I know how to dynamically add a spinner, my problem is that I am not able to modify a same list and and display in new spinner instance.

Comment: Just create a List/Array/ArrayList removing the old item, and create new adapter and spinner? No?Tell us more then!

Comment: I have tried this but didn't work.

Comment: Didn't work is not the comment, please post the code as well as the current behavior!!